# angular 2 - set a selection on an elementRef

Tags: angular, selection, contenteditable, textselection

I have this selection:

```
let selection = window.getSelection();
```

And this elementRef:

```
@ViewChild('contentEditable') public el: ElementRef;
```

And for example this text is inside the contenteditable elementRef:

> This is some text

Where i selected 'some' then lost the selection but saved it in the selection property with getSelection(). How do i set it back on the elementRef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confusing input with contentEditable. With contentEditable you need to use a range to get the selection and set the selection.

**To get the selection:**

```
let range = document.createRange();
range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
this.rangeClone = range.cloneRange();
```

This uses a combination of the Selection and Range objects in Javascript. For more info, read the docs:

[Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)

[Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)

**To set the selection:**

```
this.el.nativeElement.focus();
const sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(this.rangeClone);
```

This.el looks like this:

```
@ViewChild('contentEditable') public el: ElementRef;
```